# GNUstep Objective-C procedure entry point could not be located

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

I am new to Objective-C and I am using GNUstep to develop it on Windows. Each time I try to create a file, it compiles successfully but when I try to run the .exe I get a following error:

`procedure entry point gzdirect could not be located in dynamic link library zlib1.dll`

I don't know if this is caused by a system setting, how I compiled it, or from my source code but here is the compile command:

`C:\gnustep\bin\gcc -o hello.exe hello.m -I /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L /GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -std=c99 -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString`

And here is the hello world source code:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
  NSLog(@"Hello, world!");
  return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to build projects is to use a `GNUmakefile` text file (no extension) using your text editor:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

TOOL_NAME = Hello
Hello_OBJC_FILES = hello.m

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Then you can compile your program by just running `make` at the GNUstep "Shell" command line.

See [Building Your First Objective-C Program](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_1.html#Building-Your-First-Objective_002dC-Program).

For example:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but I get the error `make is not recognized as an internal or external command` Perhaps I should have stated this before; I am on a Windows computer. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @coder108 That's an error message from the standard Windows command prompt. I do my building from within the GNUstep Shell.